# Why can't I link my css to my ejs files?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm having issues connecting my css files to my ejs files. I think I have the standard node.js/express setup. I'm trying to connect my **main.css** file located in my public/css directory to my **index.ejs** file which is located in my views. The html and routing is working fine. Here's my **app.js** code.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var contact = require('./routes/contact');
var register_form = require('./routes/register');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In my index.ejs file, I've inserted the link in between the head tags. I've triple checked to make sure all the file names are correct.

```
 <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' href='../public/css/main.css' />
  </head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app.js you've defined the location of your static files (as you should) with: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. This allows you to refer to static files such as css with absolute pathing starting from the `public` directory.

So change the link line to
`<link type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' href='/css/main.css' />` and it should work.

It's better to use this "absolute" pathing as it allows you to move your template pages without breaking css links (eg. moving `views/index.ejs -> views/pages/index.ejs`