Why is TailwindCSS not being applied to things inside of my body tag?
I am using NodeJs, TailwindCSS, and ExpressJS to build a personal website. I am pretty new to this. I have an index.ejs file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= data.title %></title>
  <!-- Include Tailwind CSS -->
  <link href="../assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Include Custom CSS -->
  <link href="../assets/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="custom-bg">
  <!-- Header & Navbar -->
  <%- include('partials/header') %> </header>
  
  <div> <%- include('partials/user-card') %> </div>

  <%- include('partials/footer') %>    
</body>
</html>

My navbar and custom background both work but when I try to add main content beneath the navbar the TailwindCSS I apply in the other user-card.ejs file does not work at all. I am not sure where I am going wrong here and have been troubleshooting for a while. Any help would be appreciated. Attached is a picture of my webpage. I am trying to style the "Hello World".
I have tried removing my header file from the index.ejs file and just having a single body tag with no background but I still cannot style anything inside the body.
a-personal-website
├─ .DS_Store
├─ README.md
├─ assets
│  ├─ custom.css
│  └─ styles.css
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
├─ public
│  └─ images
│     ├─ background.jpeg
│     └─ cat.jpeg
├─ server.js
├─ styles
│  └─ tailwindcss.css
├─ tailwind.config.js
└─ views
   ├─ about.ejs
   ├─ contact.ejs
   ├─ index.ejs
   ├─ partials
   │  ├─ background.ejs
   │  ├─ footer.ejs
   │  ├─ header.ejs
   │  └─ user-card.ejs
   └─ projects.ejs

Server.js:
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
const port = 8008; 
const path = require('path'); 
const tailwindConfig = require('./tailwind.config');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));


@JulienP have you defined the path of your static files in server.js?

Check if you have a line like this in your server.js app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

@RoyChristo I have that exact same line in there. My navbar is also working and being styled correctly using tailwind as well so i am not sure why the user-card is not

@JulienP move your asset folder into public folder and use  absolute pathing inside your ejs files

@JulienP So after you move your asset folder to the public directory, change the link line to  and it should work.

@RoyChristo hmm I tried it but still the same issue

Kindly refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642090/why-cant-i-link-my-css-to-my-ejs-files

@RoyChristo I am still somewhat confused. I changed it to an absolute path but still getting the same issue. I can update my code to what it looks like now.

Can you inspect your app in the browser and check if your assets in public folder are available?

For debugging, please remove the line - <%- include('partials/header') %> , and see whether user-card is coming well or not.

@RoyChristo sorry for the late response but my assets folder is visible but i dont see the parent public folder
